# Adding an Archive button to posts page for administrators

Tags: posts, wp-admin, buttons

I want to add an Archive button near the `Edit, Quick Edit, Trash and View` buttons in the posts page - https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTm8f.png. I've found a nice function that can probably do just that, but I've got no idea how to use it - [wp_set_post_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_categories). What I want is to have a static `Archive` category, that isn't present in any of the menus, but due to the nature of the site (lots of orders, results etc) we have to keep them and I just don't want them to be in the trash or unpublish them after their deadline expires. I've looked through the pages to see how `Delete` button works, but I've found 30+ references to it, and I can't fathom how exactly does that work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here is something i have used before as a solution for changing the post category (or any term/taxonomy) just make sure you set the right  `$post_type,$append,$taxonomy,$terms`

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Simple Ajax set cat
Plugin URI: http://en.bainternet.info
Description: dead simple lightweight plugin to add a post row action link to set a post category by ajax
Version: 0.1
Author: Bainternet
Author Email: admin@bainternet.info
License:

  Copyright 2013 Bainternet (admin@bainternet.info)

  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2, as 
  published by the Free Software Foundation.

  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
  GNU General Public License for more details.

  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA

*/
/**
* SimpleCat
* @author Ohad Raz <admin@bainternet.info>
*/
class SimpleArchive
{
    public $post_type = 'post';
    public $append    = false;
    public $taxonomy  = 'category';
    public $terms     = array(1); //you can change this to string of term names

    /**
     * Class constructor
     *
     * @author Ohad Raz <admin@bainternet.info>
     * @since 0.1
     * @param array $args optional for feuture
     */
    function __construct($args = array()){
        //add row action link
        add_filter('post_row_actions',array($this,'_action_row'), 10, 2);
        //add javascript fp ajax call
        add_action('admin_footer-edit.php',array($this,'addJS'));
        //ajax function
        add_action('wp_ajax_setToCat', array($this,'ajaxSetToCat'));
    }
    /**
     * adds an action link to post listing row
     * @author Ohad Raz <admin@bainternet.info>
     * @since 0.1
     * @param  array  $actions row actions
     * @param  onject $post    Post object
     * @return array modified actions
     */
    function _action_row($actions, $post){
        //check for your post type
        if ($post->post_type == $this->post_type){
            $actions['archive'] = '<a href="#" class="move_TO_CAT" data-pid="'.$post->ID.'">'.__('Archive').'</a>';
        }
        return $actions;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the javascript magic to make the ajax request
     * 
     * @author Ohad Raz <admin@bainternet.info>
     * @since 0.1
     * @return void
     */
    function addJS(){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
        ?>
         <div id="status_update_working" style="background-color: green; color: #fff; font-wieght: bolder;   font-size: 22px;   height: 33px;   left: 40%;   padding: 35px;   position: fixed;   top: 100px;   width: 350px; display:none !important; "><?php _e('Changing status...'); ?></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            function ajaxSetCat(p){
                jQuery("#status_update_working").show('fast');
                jQuery.getJSON(ajaxurl,
                    {   pid: p.attr("data-pid"),
                        action: "setToCat",
                        _nonce: "<?php echo wp_create_nonce('setToCat'); ?>"
                    },
                    function(data) {
                        if (data.error){
                            alert(data.error);
                        }else{
                             alert(data.text);
                        }
                    }
                );
                jQuery("#status_update_working").hide('9500');
            }
            $('.move_TO_CAT').click(function(){
                ajaxSetCat($(this))
            });
        });
        </script>
        <?php

    }

    /**
     * ajax callback function to actually set the category
     * 
     * @author Ohad Raz <admin@bainternet.info>
     * @since 0.1
     * @return void
     */
    function ajaxSetToCat(){
        //minor validation
        if (!isset($_GET['pid']) || ! wp_verify_nonce($_GET['_nonce'], 'setToCat')){
            $re['error'] = __('something went wrong ...');
            echo json_encode($re);
            die();
        }
        $results = wp_set_post_terms( intval($_GET['pid']), $this->terms, $this->taxonomy, $this->append );
        if ( is_wp_error( $results ) ){
            $re['error'] = __('something went wrong ...') ." ". $results->get_error_message();
        }elseif($results === false || !is_array($results)){
            $re['error'] = __('something went wrong ...');
        }else{
            $re['text'] = __('Set to cat successful');
        }
        echo json_encode($re);
        die();
    }
}//end class
new SimpleArchive();
```